# Visual C# Combobox

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox, listbox, c#

Is it possible if I choose 2 in my numericupdown control I will also have 2 comboboxes??

It's that the comboboxes that will appear will vary from the value of my numericupdown button.

Or Maybe I'm thinking if i input 5 in my numeric updown I will have the choose 5 datas in my combobox and my choices will be stored in a listbox.

Because I'm making a room assignment. for example a customer wishes to rent 5 rooms I should assign him with 5 available rooms. And I want my rooms assignment to be recorded in a listbox so that I can keep track of my mistakes.. Is it Possible??

If my question violated the rule, can somebody just please post links related to this problem. I know I'm a bit annoying to this site and I am very sorry :((

Comment: It's good practice to try to do it yourself, then post here if you have specific problems (and then, including the code giving you problems in your question).  Reading [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) (in detail) in the faq should help clear things up for you.  Not my downvotes, BTW =/

Comment: @downvoters: It's good practice (for us) to try and take the time to explain your downvote.  Reading the OPs last sentence, it's clear he's quickly becoming discourage by SO.  Ok...I'm done semi-ranting now.

Comment: I think one of the reasons your question is being downvoted is that it isn't really clear what you are trying to do and/or what problem you are running into

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take some guesses as to what you are trying to do as it isn't very clear from your question.

If you are asking:

> Is it possible to create a Windows Forms dialog which dynamically
>   displays *n* ComboBox controls at runtime based on a user supplied
>   value from a NumericUpDown control?

Then the answer, is: Yes, it's possible. There are several ways to accomplish this, although the simplest would probably be to use one of the layout panels, possibly the [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx). Essentially, you would need to respond to the (probably) the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged.aspx) event on the NumericUpDown control. In that event handler, you would then need to programatically create the appropriate number of ComboBox controls (based on the value of the NumericUpDown control) and add them to the layout panel.